# NameError: name 'lt' is not defined when running GPS Python script

Tags: raspbian, python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/gps.py", line 18, in <module>
    while cd &lt>= 50:
NameError: name 'lt' is not defined
```

It is showing like this when I run the program through the terminal.

What does it mean?

Comment: Give the script and the exact error message properly formatted and someone may help.  However as the question is not specific to the Pi they may not.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NameError (not RPi specific)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like wherever you got the code, it was horribly mangled in the process. `while cd &lt>= 50:` is **not** valid syntax in Python.

It looks like the [HTML entity](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) for `<` (less than) got replaced by `&lt;` somewhere along the way; searching suggests you probably found the code [here](http://www.rhydolabz.com/wiki/?p=9557) (or someone else used the code from there without noticing the error), where the line was:

```
while cd &lt;= 50:
```

The correct code for this line should have been:

```
while cd <= 50:
```